# MySQL Create table with procedure analyze()

Tags: mysql, alter-table

Procedure Analyse() suggests the optimal field for my columns. I want to create a new table with optimal field types starting from a table that I already have. At this time I'm running

```
SELECT * FROM mytable PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

Then I copy the report and manually I write the create statement. Is there a way to do that automatically? Is it more efficient to alter a table with new field types or create a new empty table with optimal field types and re-import data?

Answer (score 1):

In truth you would not want to blindly accept the data types returned by this Analysis as you would / could never be sure what data types were "suggested". This Procedure returns "Suggested" optimal data types that "May" help reduce data storage requirements. The return values also depend on the data in the table you're selecting and could possibly change each time you run this query on new data.

Read more here on [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html)

But if you wanted to try something, I would start by building a Procedure of my own that could pass the returned data types recommended into a dynamically created DDL statement that you would need to check for possible incorrect datatypes and then execute the resulting DDL. It might take a little working out in terms of your code but you really should read more on Procedure Analyze()

Comment: I understand that dev.mysql may be dangerous in some cases. But some times I need to optimize some big datasets. So I started to use the procedure analyze very often. I never know the optimal field for a field, expecially if numeric, so I find it very usefull.